# Change the chapter font in TOC without using "tocloft" package

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, sans-serif

As using `tocloft` in `book` class produces some unexpected *side-effect*, I wonder how to change the chapter font (e.g. 1  Introduction) as sans serif without using any other packages?

For example, change the highlighted text to `sans serif font`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[lining ]{libertine}
\usepackage[ T1 ]{fontenc}

\definecolor{DarkBlue}{RGB}{0,51,153}
\usepackage[ ]{titlesec} 
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]   
  {\LARGE \color{DarkBlue}}
  {\vspace{-1 em} \flushright   \normalsize \color{black}  \MakeUppercase{  \bfseries \sffamily  \chaptertitlename } \hspace{1 em}  { \fontsize{70}{70}\selectfont \color{black} \sffamily \thechapter }} {20 pt} { \bfseries \sffamily \LARGE}    

\titleformat{\section} {\Large \bfseries \sffamily \color{DarkBlue}}     {\thesection}{1 em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}  {\large \bfseries \sffamily  \color{DarkBlue}}      {\thesubsection}{1 em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}  {\normalsize \sffamily  \bfseries      \color{DarkBlue}}  {\thesubsubsection}{1 em}{}  %\slshape
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}   % table of content depth
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Preface}

\lipsum[1-3]
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Foo}
\lipsum[1-12]
\chapter{How to make nuclear bomb}
\section{Equations}
\lipsum[1-12]
\backmatter
\chapter{Appendix~A}
\lipsum[1-12]
\chapter{Appendix~B}
\lipsum[1-12]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Without using any package or also without providing a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: The simplest manner would be to redefine `\l@chapter`, the document class must be known before saying more.

Comment: What is the unexpected side-effct you are seeing?

Comment: @PeterWilson, the spacing of TOC is changed as well as the `blank` page for LOF,LOT with `book` class

Comment: I don't think that the spacing of the TOC is changed. The manual does say that with chapters (e.g., book class) the LOF and LOT do not necessarily start on new pages. If you want that then add `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage` before calling for the LOF or LOT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>This is not really tested for lack of copy-pastable code, but should work in the `book` class.</strike> Put in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\l@chapter#1#2{%
\ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne \addpenalty {-\@highpenalty }\vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
\setlength \@tempdima {1.5em}\begingroup \parindent \z@ \rightskip\@pnumwidth
\parfillskip -\@pnumwidth \leavevmode \bfseries \advance \leftskip \@tempdima
\hskip -\leftskip {\sffamily #1}\nobreak \hfil \nobreak \hb@xt@ \@pnumwidth 
{\hss #2}\par \penalty \@highpenalty \endgroup \fi}
\makeatother
```

*Update*: if you want to achieve similar effect with `memoir` or `scrbook` then use rather the following code:

```
\makeatletter
\let\originall@chapter\l@chapter
\def\l@chapter#1#2{\originall@chapter{{\sffamily #1}}{#2}}
\makeatother
```

The above is actually preferable to the one I proposed earlier, also for the `book` class, as it will less encumber your preamble. Nevertheless the advantage of the first proposal is that you can also in case of need customize the hard-coded lengths therein.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter \def\l@chapter#1#2{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne \addpenalty {-\@highpenalty }\vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
  \setlength \@tempdima {1.5em}\begingroup \parindent \z@ \rightskip\@pnumwidth
  \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth \leavevmode \bfseries \advance \leftskip \@tempdima
  \hskip -\leftskip {\sffamily #1}\nobreak \hfil \nobreak \hb@xt@ \@pnumwidth
  {\hss #2}\par \penalty \@highpenalty \endgroup \fi} \makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{One}

\section{A}

\lipsum[1]

\section{B}

\lipsum[2]

\chapter{Two}

\section{C}

\lipsum[3]

\section{D}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image: toc]

And with the code provided in the question, one obtains:

[image: toc2]

Comment: It works perfectly!

Comment: rather than redefining `\l@chapter` the way I did, one could save the old definition, and encapsulate it in a new one with the first parameter `#1` replaced by `{\sffamily #1}`. Both methods are compatible with `hyperref`. Note though that I had to put `\sffamily #1` in a group to limit the scope of the font change. I think this will be in `99.9%` of the cases with no after-effect elsewhere.

Comment: @KOF: please not that if you change your document class to `memoir` or `scrbook` then the proposed method is not the good one. It would be better to do the alternative I mentioned in my comment.

Comment: only original document classes are used for my writting `:)`, because I don't know what kind of weird settings in these classes.

Comment: `memoir` actually has most (if not all, I don't know)  of the `tocloft` commands and functionalities. Both `memoir` and `scrbook` are well documented: [memman](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) and [scrguien](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf)

Comment: All of the these manual are over 300 - 500 pages, which are even bigger than normal textbooks! I just do some necessary modifications to the basic classes to satisfy my need. I thought that would be great  if there is short version along with the full version.